# Where to put DTD in gzipped files?

Tags: php, gzip, dtd

I'm adding the following:

> ```
> <?php ob_start( 'ob_gzhandler' ); ?>
> ```

To a file to enable `gzip` compression.

Should it go before the `DTD`, or between it and the `<html>` tag?

Comment: If you're going to downvote me, let me know why, OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to go before the DTD and *any* other output. The `<` of `<?php` must be the absolute first byte of the file otherwise there is literal output before it (even if that's only whitespace, or a UTF-8 fake-BOM emitted by a misguided Windows text editor).

Any `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration in a .php file is just pure output text, something that applies to the returned HTML page and not the PHP file itself (as PHP is neither HTML nor XML).

Answer (score 2):

Before all data sent to browser ^^